# Apps won't launch in Mac OS Sierra

Tags: macos

I can launch applications from the dock. But when I launch apps from the applications folder, they do not open. Another odd symptom: in Preview with the app closed, in some folders I can open an image by just clicking on it. But in other folders, a jpeg will not open. But, if I launch Preview via the dock I can open up all images. Any ideas?

Update: Restarting in Safe Mode made it worse. After restart, I could not access anything. Any folder or app that I tried to access would cause the screen to "blink".

But I could access items on an external hard drive (Time Machine backup). I ultimately used time machine to restore the computer.

Comment: Have you booted into Safe Mode? Restart your Mac and hold down the Shift key until you get to the login window. Try out launching apps in safe mode and let us know. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262